# Git: fatal: could not set 'core.filemode' to 'true'

Tags: git

When trying to clone a repository with a command like:

```
git clone ssh://myuserid@myhost/mypath/myrepo.git
```

I'm getting the following errors:

> Cloning into 'myrepo'...
>
> error: failed to write new configuration file /path/myrepo/.git/config.lock
>
> fatal: could not set 'core.filemode' to 'true'

Any ideas what the problem could be?  A Google search yielded nothing.

Comment: Do you have write access to the destination folder?

Comment: Yes, I have write access to the destination folder.  In fact, I can successfully execute the following commands:mkdir -p /path/myrepo/.git; touch /path/myrepo/.git/config.lock;

Comment: Try cloning to a completely different place. One you _know_ you have access to.

Comment: When I try cloning in my home directory, the clone seems to make more progress but fails because there is not enough disk space on the home directory's partition.  So I think evolutionxbox is on to something.  Maybe there's something fishy about the destination.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50242563/7976758

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+could+not+set+%27core.filemode%27+to+%27true%27

Comment: What version of git are you running?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem was that the original target partition had insufficient disk space.  I don't understand why the error message did not indicate that, but once I mounted a device at /path that had plenty of space all was well.