# how to fix error: chmod on /mnt/x/coding/webapp/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted fatal: could not set 'core.filemode' to 'false'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, bash, permissions, chmod

```
almanex@LAPTOP-GHRH09TN:~$ cd /mnt/x/
almanex@LAPTOP-GHRH09TN:/mnt/x$ mkdir -p coding
almanex@LAPTOP-GHRH09TN:/mnt/x$ cd coding
almanex@LAPTOP-GHRH09TN:/mnt/x/coding$ rails new webapp
      create
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
error: chmod on /mnt/x/coding/webapp/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted
fatal: could not set 'core.filemode' to 'false'
```

Hello, I'm trying to create an app on rails but there is an issue with chmod, I've searched the net but there is only one solution that I found and already tried (as you can see): creating the directory with -p option. This did not help. Do you have some ideas what should I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO. `-p` has nothing to do with file permissions. It will only make parent dir if it doesn't exist.   Try executing the command with  `sudo`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git init: fatal: could not set 'core.filemode' to 'false'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50108363/git-init-fatal-could-not-set-core-filemode-to-false)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue but with git clone, adding a `sudo` before the command fixed it for me.

ie `sudo rails new webapp`